# How to change ToggleButton IsPressed state?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'd like to change the IsPressed state of a ToggleButton via C#.  Unfortunately i get the message that says "The property or indexer 'ButtonBase.IsPressed' cannot be used in the context....".

Is there a way to set it via C# code?

[Screen capture of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9NWz.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend ToggleButton with this functionality and write your own ToggleButton.

```cs
public class PressableToggelButton : ToggleButton
{
    public new bool? IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return base.IsChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            base.IsChecked = value;

            if(value == true)
            {
                base.IsPressed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                base.IsPressed = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Be careful, the new IsChecked hides the base property, which can lead to side effects. Please adapt this idea to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The property you are looking for is "IsChecked". IsPressed is a property on ButtonBase which indicates that the left mouse button or SPACEBAR is pressed over the button.

```
this.MyToggleButton.IsChecked = true;
```

Comment: Actually it isn't, that does "uncheck" it, but it still leaves it in a selected state.  I want it uncheck and unactive, the way it is before you touched the button at all.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what you mean by “selected state” if the button is unchecked?

Comment: Yes, just uploaded it to the original question above.  You can see three buttons, which are pressed, not checked.